# CSS, fill all div width with text

Tags: html, css

How to automatically change the space between the letters.I want the text to take up the entire width of the div. Text is not static. (Always changing text, can be 123" or "text text"...)

```
  <style type="text/css">
    #menu{
      width: 200px;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #336699;
      font-size: 16px;
      letter-spacing: 100%;
    }
  </style>
<body>
<div id="menu">
  tekstas
</div>
```

Comment: No disrespect meant towards JamWaffles, but seriously, how does an answer that is (initially) incorrect and doesn't even come close to a solution gets both accepted and 5 upvotes ?! Sheesh ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** Unfortunately this only changes *word* spacing, not *letter* spacing. There is not way to do kerning in CSS. Possibly CSS3, however.

This is easily accomplished with the `text-align: justify` CSS attribute:

```
#menu 
{ 
      width: 200px; 
      background-color: #000; 
      color: #336699; 
      font-size: 16px; 
      text-align: justify; 
}
```

Comment: justify takes care of word spacing not letter spacing

Comment: Ooops! My apologies there. I was a little hasty with my reply >slap<

Comment: Also, it only affects rows that are followed by another row.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way of doing this purely with CSS. The `letter-spacing` attribute doesn't take percent values. `text-align: justify` won't work either because it only affects the space between words, not the font kerning and it also only applies to those rows of text that are followed by another row.

You could try using JS to do this by counting the number of characters in a particular `div` and then calculate the needed space between the characters so it would fill out the width, but this solution would only work right with mono-spaced fonts (fonts that have the same width for all the characters).

Comment: Would `letter-spacing` work with pixel values? (ie. the width of the div if it's fixed?)

Comment: Yes, `letter-spacing` does work with pixel values, but it will simply add the declared value between the characters, or substract it, if a negative value is given.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution will not work for everyone, but it turned out to solve the problem for me: if you are displaying a short amount of headline text, you can put a space between every character of every word "L i k e  t h i s".

For my particular design, this happens to look fine, and of course it allows `align: justify` to fully do its magic within the div.