# Insert a space after every Character in CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's assume we have this html:

```
<h2>TITLE</h2>
```

Is it possible, through the power of CSS alone, to make this either be or behave like:

```
<h2>T I T L E</h2>
```

Reason being that I want to justify the letters over a given width in the title, and I don't want to resort to serverside regular expression witchcraft before having properly evaluated the CSS options.

I already managed to justify the single letters through CSS using these rules:

```
h2 {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 200px; // for example
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've looked into `text-replace`, but there's no support in any major browser. Other than that, I've not yet found any hopeful candidate.

CSS3 would be ok if there's ok support, JS is not of any help.

**UPDATE**

`letter-spacing` is not an option since it has to adjust to the width dynamically AND I do not want to check browser implementation of kerning perpetually. But thanks to the guys suggesting it, I knew I had forgot something when formulating the question :)

[Here's a jsfiddle for fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/9av3m/)

Comment: Do you want spaces, or do you mean you want the characters equally spaced to fill the width?

Comment: @jaypeagi the latter, but also for text without spaces - it should behave like it had spaces after every element.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334126/css-fill-all-div-width-with-text

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Thanks - To justify the text is not the problem, it is just to justify single letters to a dynamic width

Comment: Why not just change the HTML? I've done this before and when I want it to be display "normally" I use a negative `letter-spacing`.

Comment: @gvee technically I do not want to do this since it will look awful on google...

Answer (score 10):

Why not just use letter-spacing?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

Comment: The problem with letter-spacing is that a) I have to set the letter-spacing individually for each title I have and b) also individually for each browser since kerning differs a lot. With user input, this is just not feasible.

Comment: In that case, I don't know of any other way to do it other than javascript.

Answer (score 5):

A much easier way to do this would be to use the letter spacing css styling.

for example

```
h2 {
      letter-spacing:10px;
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS's [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing):

```
h2 {
  letter-spacing: 2em;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A22yW/)

Comment: Yeah, got a hat for this :)